# Delphi: Method resolution clauses not being applied when getting/setting properties through RTTI

Tags: delphi, rtti

I am trying to add functionality to existing code, by using method resolution clause for various interface properties.

While this works fine, when getting / setting properties in code, this fails when trying to set or get the properties through RTTI.

When using RTTI, the 1st implementing class method is being called.

Here is code which shows the problem:

```
program TestIntfMethodResolutions;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants,
  System.Classes,
  TypInfo,
  RTTI{,
  uRTTIHelper};


type
   ITestInterface = interface
   ['{61553B5F-574A-4B0F-AB6F-0560E324B463}']
    function GetA:integer;
    procedure SetA(const AVal:integer);
    property A:integer read GetA write SetA;
    end;

   {$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([vcPrivate,vcPublic])}
   TTintimpl1 = class(TInterfacedObject,ITestInterface)
    private
    FA:integer;
    function GetA: integer;

    procedure SetA(const Value: integer);virtual; // Does not need to be virtual

    public
      property A:integer read GetA write SetA;

    end;

   {$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([vcPrivate,vcPublic])}

   //Explicit RTTI settings causes the Private methods to show up in the method list
   TIntimpl2 = class(TTIntimpl1,ITestInterface)
    private
      procedure MySetA(const Value:integer);virtual;

    public
      procedure ITestInterface.SetA = MySetA;

    end;

  TMain = class

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure FormCreate;
    end;

var
  Form5: TMain;

procedure TMain.FormCreate;
var
  ctx:TRttiContext;
  avalue,bvalue:tvalue;
  atype,bastyp:TRttiType;
  aproplist:Tarray<TRttiProperty>;
  amethlist:Tarray<TRttiMethod>;
  isinst:boolean;
  aninst:TRttiInstanceType;
  anintf:TRttiInterfaceType;
  intflist:Tarray<TRttiInterfaceType>;
  inst:pointer;
  anint:ITestInterface;
  aprop:TRttiProperty;
  codeptr:pointer;
  asetmeth:TRTTIMethod;

begin
  ctx:=TRttiContext.Create;

  //Faxisloopthr:=TIntimpl2.Create;

  anint:=TIntimpl2.Create;

  avalue:=anint as TObject;
  atype:=ctx.GetType(avalue.TypeInfo);

  if atype.IsInstance then
    begin
      aninst:=atype.AsInstance;
      aproplist:=aninst.GetProperties;
      amethlist:=aninst.GetMethods;

      bvalue:=TValue.FromOrdinal(aproplist[0].PropertyType.Handle,1);
      inst:=avalue.AsObject;
      aprop:=aproplist[0]; //I could have called aproplist[0].SetValue(...
      aprop.SetValue(inst,bvalue);
      end;

  writeln('RTTI result '+anint.A.ToString); //Should give me 20 but I get 10 everytime


  //asetmeth:=aprop.SetterMethod(inst); // returns SetA and not MySetA - need uRTTIhelper unit. https://github.com/RRUZ/blog/tree/master/RTTI

//      setpropvalue(inst,aprop.PropInfo,bvalue.AsVariant); // calls SetA and not MySetA

  //Manually setting the value calls the correct method

  anint.A:=1;
  writeln('Direct setting '+anint.A.ToString);

  end;


{ T2ndIntf }


{ TTintimpl1 }

function TTintimpl1.GetA: integer;
begin
  Result:=FA;
  end;

procedure TTintimpl1.SetA(const Value: integer);
var
  a:integer;
begin
  FA:=Value*10;
  writeln('In SetA ',FA);
  end;

{ TIntimpl2 }


//Should get called - but the 1st implementing parent gets called
procedure TIntimpl2.MySetA(const Value: integer);

begin
  FA:=Value*20;
  writeln('In MySetA ',FA);
  end;

begin
  Form5:=TMain.Create;
  try
    Form5.FormCreate;
  finally
    Form5.Free;
    readln;
    end;

  end.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks,

IB.
Delphi 10.2 Tokyo Win64

Comment: Hardly surprising that the interface method resolution is nlignored given that you don't use the interface

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - The interface resolution is only ignored when using RTTI. It works as expected when I set the property in code. Can you guide me to the correct way to set declared interface properties declared using RTTI. Thanks.

Comment: You need to go via the interface. Your RTTI code goes via the class.

Comment: Thanks David. Yes, it works when I access the methods through the interface. But unfortunately, no RTTI is generated for the interface properties as it is (as someone put it) just syntactic sugar. It was easier to rewrite the logic to avoid the troubling interfaces altogether. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You have to call the property getter and setter directly, but you can do that through RTTI